# how to test my application on a real Android device?

Tags: android-studio

I recently started using android studio and I created an app on android studio that I would test on my cellphone, when I connect the device to the computer android studio can not read my phone.
Do I have to connect the phone or just do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before connecting your phone to the computer you first have to turn on USB debugging.

To do that:

1. Turn on developer options by going to the about phone section in
   settings.
2. Click on the Build Number quickly 5 times and it will
   turn on Developer Settings(if not already on).
3. Go to developer settings and then find USB debugging option, and turn it on.

Now when you'll connect to your computer and try to run the from Android Studio, it will show you a dialogue on the phone that a computer wants to connect, click 'allow' and you're done.

If it doesn't show your device on Android Studio, try searching for your device drivers first.

Answer (score 0):

Many different options here.

1. You can build the apk, upload it to your dropbox account, and download it and install it on your phone.
2. Move an apk from your computer that you built onto your phone manually if your phone is setup as a "file device".

You can also read more [Here on the developer.android.com website.](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) If you phone is not being recognized by the computer, [make sure you install the OEM drivers.](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html)